# Generate UUID for Cassandra in Python

Tags: python, cassandra, uuid, pycassa

Heh,
I'm using

`cf.insert(uuid.uuid1().bytes_le, {'column1': 'val1'})`  (pycassa)

to create a TimeUUID for Cassandra, but getting the error

```
InvalidRequestException: 
InvalidRequestException(why='UUIDs must be exactly 16 bytes')
```

It doesn't work with

```
uuid.uuid1()
uuid.uuid1().bytes
str(uuid.uuid1())
```

either.

What's the best way to create a valid TimeUUID to use with the CompareWith="TimeUUIDType" flag?

Thanks,
Henrik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must ensure your column family schema accepts UUID as key. Your code will work with a column family created as (using cassandra-cli):

```
create column family MyColumnFamily
  with column_type = 'Standard'
  and comparator = 'AsciiType'
  and default_validation_class = 'BytesType'
  and key_validation_class = 'TimeUUIDType';
```

To add values to this CF:

```
import pycassa
pool = pycassa.ConnectionPool('Keyspace1')
cf = pycassa.ColumnFamily(pool, 'MyColumnFamily')
cf.insert(uuid.uuid1(), {'column1': 'val1'})
```

Answer (score 9):

Looks like you are using the uuid as the row key and not the column name.

The '**compare_with: TimeUUIDType**' attribute specifies that the column names will be compared with using the TimeUUIDType, i.e it [tells Cassandra how to sort the *columns* for slicing operations](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/StorageConfiguration)

Have you considered using any of the high level python clients? E.g. [Tradedgy](http://github.com/enki/tragedy/), [Lazy Boy](http://github.com/enki/tragedy/), [Telephus](http://github.com/driftx/Telephus/tree/master) or [Pycassa](http://github.com/vomjom/pycassa)

Comment: I should've mentioned that I'm usig pycassa, but it seems that I have to create the timeuuids myself.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. I am having the same problem, would it be possible for you to give some more details?

Comment: you know the difference between keys and column names?